# Can fonts prevent disabling ligatures?

Tags: css, fonts

I wish to disable ligatures for a website, using CSS.

Font used: Cinzel Decorative (from fonts.google.com)

However, in Chrome 83, the CSS rules to disable ligatures have no effect on this font.

Can a font prevent using CSS to disable the ligatures?

```css
* {
        font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
        font-variant-ligatures: none !important;
        font-feature-settings: "liga" 0 !important;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel+Decorative&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h1>he and too have ligatures</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the same happen in Firefox to